# Can't load woocommerce default checkout js and plugins js

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I've searched a lot to find a useful answer, with no success... I'm new to woocoomerce, although I've almost finished to developed my store. I'm stuck on checkout. I can't purchase any products of my site with my developed theme. I've tried with storefront theme and it works just fine.

I know that some default scripts are not been loaded such as plugins scripts (like my payment platform), and I don't know how to include them.

I am using pagar.me as payment platform, by the way.

Comment: Where is your code?  How are we supposed to know what's working and what's not?

Comment: What do you need specifically? I can share my footer.php, a link to test and anything else you need,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! It was just a noobish mistake... I forgot to add wp_head in my header.php file. I thought I had added, but no.